# Using the same Skype number on computer and phone

Tags: skype

I have a Skype account on my computer. I have a need to have the same number on my cell phone.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Skype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider) application for your phone
2. Login using your Skype ID & Password (which you are using on your system).

Answer (score 1):

Your Skype account information is held on the Skype servers, not your local device, so from Skype installed anywhere you can just login with the same Skype name and password. I agree with the first answer.